# how to use auto_complete with rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, autocomplete

After searching on the web I got a problem :

I use rails3 and I do the following command

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/patshaughnessy/auto_complete.git
```

then i restart my rails server

my `index.html.erb` :

```
<%= text_field_with_auto_complete :departement, :nom, {}, {:method => :get} %>
```

my controller :

```
class AutocompController < ApplicationController
  auto_complete_for :departement, :nom
end
```

I got a model like :

```
class CreateDepartements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :departements do |t|
      t.column :region_id, :integer
      t.column :num_dept, :string
      t.column :nom, :string
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :departements
  end
end
```

my routes.rb :

```
 resources :autocomp, :collection => { :auto_complete_for_departement_nom => :get }
```

I get the following error :

> No route matches {:controller=>"autocomp", :action=>"auto_complete_for_departement_nom"}

I don't get why it doesn't work? is auto_complete compatible with rails3? Or should I use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the route. Its missing, therefor you get this message.

Goto config/routes.rb and add your route, like:

```
resources : departements do
    get : auto_complete_for_departement_nom, :on => :collection
end
```

Im using, [autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete)